# Hive Text format with multi line column to ORC

Tags: hadoop, text, hive, orc

When a hive table in text format with multiline column gets converted to ORC format, it fails to read the columns right.

**Hive table with custom record delimiter**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MULTILINE_XML_TXT
(id INT, name STRING, xml STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/practice/xml/multiline/mysql/text/in/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('textinputformat.record.delimiter'='#');
```

The xml column in the above table has data in multiple lines.
When i query from this table, i see the data right.

**Sample data (2 rows) in the above table**

```
100  xyz  <employees><employee><age>26</age>
</employee><employee><age>45</age>
</employee></employees>
200  abc  <employees><employee><age>20</age>
</employee><employee>
<age>50</age></employee></employees>
```

I created another table with the ORC format and copied data from the text table to the ORC table, but the conversion is not correct.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MULTILINE_XML_ORC
(id INT, name STRING, xml STRING) STORED AS ORC;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE MULTILINE_XML_ORC
SELECT id, name, xml FROM MULTILINE_XML_TXT;
```

Executing the query `select * from MULTILINE_XML_ORC` gives the following result, which is incorrect.

```
100    xyz    <employees><employee><age>26</age>
NULL   NULL   NULL
NULL   NULL   NULL
NULL   NULL   NULL
NULL   abc    <employees><employee><age>20</age>
NULL   NULL   NULL
NULL   NULL   NULL
NULL   NULL   NULL
NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The "sample data" you show does not look like the result from a SELECT from `MULTILINE_XML_TXT`, rather a sample of the raw text file.

Comment: AFAIK the TEXT SerDe will assume that any control character(s) indicating an end-of-line for sane people (i.e. `\n` or `\r\n` or `\r`) mean end-of-record. So you cannot load that junk file as-is.

Comment: On the other hand, if you can find a way to make a difference between line-break-in-junk-XML-field and line-break-meaning end-of-record *(can you define a deterministic rule for that, by the way??? I''m not so sure)* then **you can write a custom SerDe** for your custom file format. For example https://github.com/msukmanowsky/OmnitureDataFileInputFormat

Comment: Personally I would just `sed` the original file to remove the extra line breaks; they make no difference for XML parsers anyway.

Comment: You are right, the sample data was not from the table but i have updated now. The text table is table to read the data fine.

Comment: What i do is, load the data from mysql to hdfs, create external text table and then load in to an ORC table. If i import from mysql as avro then avro reads the pretty xml right. When i import from mysql i provide the fields and the line separators as xml itself has line breaks. The text table is perfectly fine. If text table is fine then what makes ORC not work is what i wonder.

Comment: My guess is that Hive Mappers read data from the TEXT input file and write it to temp HDFS files (probably as SEQUENCEFILE), then the Reducers read these temp files but **mess up** with the embedded EOL. Do you have a Reduce step in your INSERT? Or a merge-small-files step?

Comment: Any difference if you change ORC with SEQUENCEFILE, by the way?